# how to go From a UIViewConttroller to an Scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

the SoundControoler is the UIViewControlloer that I am currently at and i need to get the GameScene which is an Skcene.

Code:

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameKit
import UIKit
import iAd

class SoundController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }
```

I know how to go to the UIViewController(SoundBoardController) from the SKcene but can't figure out how to do it the other way around.Below is the code I used to go from the SKcene to the ViewController.

```
 func GotoSoundBoard(){
    var vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
    vc.performSegueWithIdentifier("SoundSegue", sender: vc)
}
```

Below is the SKcene i need to get to

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation
import SpriteKit 
import GameKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at unwind segues. It has been asked previously. Take a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them).